# Deleting iso file used to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox, iso, delete

I have installed Ubuntu on VirtualBox using an iso file stored on Desktop. Please, how can I delete that iso file? If I deleted it in Windows, Ubuntu didn't start.

Comment: In case you did not install but only run it from a "live session" of Ubuntu (which is also possible) you will still need the ISO for installing.

Answer (score 2):

You have to open the Virtual Media Manager window. Under Ubuntu's Virtual Box it is located under File -> Virtual Media Managers. Then you can go to the Optical disks tab and delete the iso image from there. Once deleted, you can remove the actual iso image file stored on your Windows host.

[image]

In addition, I would recommend to open the settings of your virtual machine and delete the iso image from the  Storage tab. Typically if you delete actual iso image, the virtual box will complain and you have to remove the iso from list in Virtual Media Manager like I said before, but just to avoid extra unforseen issues , delete it from Storage tab as well

Comment: Thank you very much. I deleted it from Settings-> Storage --> Attributes CD/DVD Drive:

Comment: And what is the result ?

Comment: After that I could delete the .iso file used in installing of Ubuntu on VirtualBox.